# Location of adverb (?) in sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbs

Which placement of "from above" is correct in this sentence?

1) The o-ring is pressed onto the sample from above.

or

2) The o-ring is pressed from above onto the sample.

I feel that the first sentence, 1), is correct, but mostly due to the fact that 2) seems to be translated from German too literally. I also feel that I have heard the 1) formulation more often.

Given that "feel" is not a good way to be sure about grammar I would be happy to learn why one of the sentences is correct.

PS: I called "from above" an adverb here for lack of better knowledge ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are grammatical. The first draws special attention to the fact that the o-ring is applied from above; it is the least "natural" but there may very well be situations where that special emphasis is necessary. The sentence might appear in a context where the orientation of components is the main focus, say.

From above, the o-ring is pressed onto the sample.

The o-ring is pressed from above onto the sample.

The o-ring is pressed onto the sample from above.

Comment: Thank you, it is useful to know that all of these can be used and I would have never come up with the first one!